# Is there an equivalent to "tr" within SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

To remind you, `tr`

> reads a byte stream from its standard input and writes the result to
>   the standard output. As arguments, it takes two sets of characters
>   (generally of the same length), and replaces occurrences of the
>   characters in the first set with the corresponding elements from the
>   second set. -- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr_%28Unix%29)

I need to this within the context of an UPDATE statement and, ideally, without doing 26 nested REPLACE function calls.

**EDIT:**
For you nosy-Parkers who just have to know what I'm doing: I want to make the in-database equivalent of [upsidedowntext.com](http://www.upsidedowntext.com/).  Right now, I do this:

```
SELECT
REVERSE(
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(UPPER(value),
 'A', 'ɐ'),
 'B', 'q'),
 'C', 'ɔ'),
 'D', 'p'),
 'E', 'ǝ'),
 'F', 'ɟ'),
 'G', 'b'),
 'H', 'ɥ'),
 'I', 'ı'),
 'J', 'ظ'),
 'K', 'ʞ'),
 'L', 'ן'),
 'M', 'ɯ'),
 'N', 'u'),
 'O', 'o'),
 'P', 'd'),
 'Q', 'b'),
 'R', 'ɹ'),
 'S', 's'),
 'T', 'ʇ'),
 'U', 'n'),
 'V', 'ʌ'),
 'W', 'ʍ'),
 'X', 'x'),
 'Y', 'ʎ'),
 'Z', 'z')) from table;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I've had to do this, and I wrote N nested `REPLACE` calls. It's a PITA.

Comment: The function is also called `translate`, but it is not available in MySQL.

Comment: Not that I know if it exists or not - but if it doesn't it should be possible to write the same functionality in a function I suppose.

Comment: If you gave an idea of what you want to tr we might be able to come up with creative solutions...